# Check all opened windows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I want a code to check all of the opened windows in my desktop, using vba.

That includes applications' windows as well.

I also need to know the windows names.

In general I want to know if the application Winrar is proceeding a specific operation, for example when I add files to an archive then the Winrar's desktop window is named as "Updating archive x", I want to get this text in my vba code.

I need the exact same thing for more applications as well, so it'd be nice to get a function for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) and [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) API functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found all the declares for the two functions. This give output like this

```
Order   Level   WindowText  ClassName   HWnd    ParentHWnd  ProcessID   ParentProcessID ThreadID    ModuleNameHWin  EXENameProcess
1   0   MSCTFIME UI MSCTFIME UI 16253876    16253876    3288    6640    7404    C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\Editor\EditorSdi\Ed.exe    explorer.exe
2   0   Default IME IME 9503286 16253876    3288    6640    7404    «Not Available Error=126»   explorer.exe
```

It expects to find a textedit control to write to.

```
Public Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetMapMode Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetStringTypeEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStringTypeExA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal dwInfoType As Long, ByVal lpSrcStr As String, ByVal cchSrc As Long, ByRef lpCharType As Integer) As Long
Public Declare Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetTempFileName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempFileNameA" (ByVal lpszPath As String, ByVal lpPrefixString As String, ByVal wUnique As Long, ByVal lpTempFileName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
Public Declare Function GetTopWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowModuleFileName Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowModuleFileNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal WinModule As String, StringLength As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long

      Private Declare Function Process32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
      Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal Handle As Long) As Long
      Private Declare Function Process32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
     Private Declare Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal th32ProcessID As Long) As Long

     Private Declare Function GetVersionExA Lib "kernel32" _
         (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Integer
      Private Type PROCESSENTRY32
         dwSize As Long
         cntUsage As Long
         th32ProcessID As Long           ' This process
         th32DefaultHeapID As Long
         th32ModuleID As Long            ' Associated exe
         cntThreads As Long
         th32ParentProcessID As Long     ' This process's parent process
         pcPriClassBase As Long          ' Base priority of process threads
         dwFlags As Long
         szExeFile As String * 260 ' MAX_PATH
      End Type

      Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
         dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
         dwMajorVersion As Long
         dwMinorVersion As Long
         dwBuildNumber As Long
         dwPlatformId As Long           '1 = Windows 95 2 = Windows NT
         szCSDVersion As String * 128
      End Type

       Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1024
       Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ = 16
       Private Const MAX_PATH = 260
       Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = &HF0000
       Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
      'STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED Or SYNCHRONIZE Or &HFFF
       Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
       Private Const TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = &H2&
       Private Const hNull = 0
       Private Const GW_CHILD = 5
       Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsWindowUnicode Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare Function OSWinHelp% Lib "user32" Alias "WinHelpA" (ByVal hwnd&, ByVal HelpFile$, ByVal wCommand%, dwData As Any)
Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "OLE32.DLL" (pGuid As GUID) As Long

Sub mnuInsertWindowList_Click()
'    WindowChain = 0
    Dim hwnd As Long
        hwnd = GetTopWindow(0)
        If hwnd <> 0 Then
            AddChildWindows hwnd, 0
        End If
End Sub


Private Function AddChildWindows(ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal Level As Long) As String
      Dim gwfnhwnd As Long, X As Long, WT As String, CN As String, Length As Long, hwnd As Long, TID As Long, PID As Long, MN As String, Ret As Long, Parenthwnd As Long
        Static Order As Long
        Static FirstTime As Long
        Parenthwnd = hwndParent
        If Level = 0 Then
                        hwnd = hwndParent
        Else
            hwnd = GetWindow(hwndParent, GW_CHILD)
        End If
        Do While hwnd <> 0
                 WT = Space(512)
                  Length = GetWindowText(hwnd, WT, 508)
                  WT = Left$(WT, Length)
                  If WT = "" Then WT = Chr(171) & "No Window Text " & Err.LastDllError & Chr(187)
                  CN = Space(512)
                  Length = GetClassName(hwnd, CN, 508)
                  CN = Left$(CN, Length)
                  If CN = "" Then CN = "Error=" & Err.LastDllError


                  TID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, PID)

                  MN = Space(512)
                  Length = GetWindowModuleFileName(hwnd, MN, 508)
                  If Length = 0 Then
                    MN = Chr(171) & "Not Available Error=" & Err.LastDllError & Chr(187)
                  Else
                    MN = Left$(MN, Length)
                  End If


                 Dim f As Long, sname As String, PList As String, PPID As Long
                 Dim hSnap As Long, proc As PROCESSENTRY32, Temp As String
                 hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
                 If hSnap = hNull Then Exit Function
                 proc.dwSize = LenB(proc)
                 ' Iterate through the processes
                 f = Process32First(hSnap, proc)
                 Do
                        If PID = proc.th32ProcessID Then
                            sname = StrZToStr(proc.szExeFile)
                            PPID = proc.th32ParentProcessID
                        End If
                        f = Process32Next(hSnap, proc)
                 Loop While f = 1
                  Order = Order + 1
'                  CStr(Order) & " HWnd=" & FormatNumber$(hwnd, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " Parent HWnd=" & FormatNumber$(Parenthwnd, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " Level=" & CStr(Level) & WT & " (" & CN & ")" & " PID=" & FormatNumber$(PID, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " TID=" & FormatNumber$(TID, 0, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbFalse) & " Module Name:" & MN & " ExeName:" & sname & vbCrLf
                If FirstTime = 0 Then
                    txtNote.SelText = vbCrLf & "Order" & vbTab & "Level" & vbTab & "WindowText" & vbTab & "ClassName" & vbTab & "HWnd" & vbTab & "ParentHWnd" & vbTab & "ProcessID" & vbTab & "ParentProcessID" & vbTab & "ThreadID" & vbTab & "ModuleNameHWin" & vbTab & "EXENameProcess"
                    FirstTime = 1
                End If
                txtNote.SelText = vbCrLf & CStr(Order) & vbTab & CStr(Level) & vbTab & WT & vbTab & CN & vbTab & CStr(hwnd) & vbTab & CStr(Parenthwnd) & vbTab & CStr(PID) & vbTab & CStr(PPID) & vbTab & CStr(TID) & vbTab & MN & vbTab & sname

                  AddChildWindows hwnd, Level + 1
                  hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop
      End Function
```

Comment: I've checked your function, however it's not doing what I wanted.

Comment: You got the idea though, and it's supposed to do it well, but when i'm importing files to a winrar window for example then its window text is different, in your code it appears as WT="WinRAR", but in task manager it appears as "Paused, press "Continue" to resume".

Comment: I've thought about the PID thing though a few moments before you posted that, and it may be a solution as well, knowing the PID is the same as knowing the window.
Although if you're interested, you can try to find a solution.
Try importing files to a winrar archive while stopping the transfer, then try to get the window text as it seems in windows.

Comment: Ty for the comment and for the help, your function is awesome in my opinion, using recursion as well, but too long XD.